# ngOptions not selecting the default option

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with a list of users.
Each user can belong to a group. Group is selected in a `<select>` menu, each has id and name. **After page load, proper group is not selected in the  menu.** When choosing a different option in the menu, user.group_id gets updated properly.

My code:

```
<select
ng-model="user.group_id"
ng-options="group.id as group.name for group in groups">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check adding `ng-value="1"` will solve your issue. Basically this solves similar issues with Radio / Checkbox options.

```
  <select ng-options="group.id as group.name for group in groups"
      ng-model="selectedGroup" ></select>
```

Refer the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vwBPE4?p=preview) for detailed implementation.

You need to assign the selected value to a scope based variable in order to handle the selections.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that user.group_id when received from the server was a string instead, while group.id was an integer. Changing user.group_id to integer solved the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to solve the problem while avoiding conversion?